# AES encryption C++ (can't decrypt encrypted file)

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm playing around with AES and write the iv and derived key to the file so that I use it later for decryption...

following function encrypts the file and saves the iv and derived key into the file, it also saves encrypted text into separate file:

```
void MainWindow::on_button_encrypt() try
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace Gtk;
    using namespace CryptoPP;

    fstream file;

    file.open(m_file_name + ".aes", std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        // get the plain password:
        SecByteBlock password;
        password_dialog get_passwd(password);
        get_passwd.run();


        // generate random salt
        const int SALT_SIZE = 32;
        SecByteBlock salt(SALT_SIZE);
        AutoSeededRandomPool prng;
        prng.GenerateBlock(salt.BytePtr(), SALT_SIZE);


        // derive a key from password and salt:
        SecByteBlock key(AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
        PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<SHA512> gen;
        gen.DeriveKey(key.BytePtr(), key.size(), 1, password.BytePtr(), password.size(), salt.BytePtr(), salt.size(), 200);


        // genereate random iv:
        SecByteBlock iv(AES::BLOCKSIZE);
        OS_GenerateRandomBlock(false, iv.BytePtr(), AES::BLOCKSIZE);


        // encrypt plain text:
        AES::Encryption enc(key.BytePtr(), AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
        CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption mode(enc, iv);

        string cipher_text;
        StringSink* sink = new StringSink(cipher_text);
        StreamTransformationFilter encryptor(mode, sink);

        string plain_text = m_file_buffer->get_text();
        encryptor.Put(reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(plain_text.c_str()), plain_text.length() + 1);
        encryptor.MessageEnd();

        // write the result:
        file << cipher_text.c_str();
        file.close();
        file.open(m_file_name + ".key", std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);
        file << key << '\n' << iv;
        file.close();
   }
}
// catch ...
```

The above function writes the iv and derived key to the file.

> 0000000002F9F140
>
> 0000000002F9F4E0

Following function is supposed to read the file and decrypt it by using the *.key file:

```
void MainWindow::on_button_decrypt()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace CryptoPP;
    Gtk::MessageDialog info("Info");

    fstream file;
    file.open("decrypted.txt", ios::out | ios::trunc);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        // read the key:
        fstream stream;
        string input;

        SecByteBlock key(AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
        SecByteBlock iv(AES::BLOCKSIZE);


        stream.open("test.txt.key", std::ios::in);

        if (stream.is_open())
        {
            getline(stream, input);
            key.Assign(reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(input.c_str()), input.size());
            input.clear();
            getline(stream, input);
            iv.Assign(reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(input.c_str()), input.size());
        }
        else
        {
            info.set_secondary_text("can't read key file");
            info.run();
            return;
        }


        // decrypt:
        AES::Decryption dec(key, AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
        CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption mode(dec, iv);

        string plain_text;
        StringSink* sink = new StringSink(plain_text);
        StreamTransformationFilter decryptor(mode, sink);
        
        try
        {
            // get encrypted text from buffer (obtained from other function):
            string cipher_text = m_file_buffer->get_text();
            decryptor.Put(reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(cipher_text.c_str()), cipher_text.size());
            decryptor.MessageEnd();
            file << plain_text;
            file.close();
        }
        catch (CryptoPP::Exception& ex)
        {
            info.set_secondary_text(ex.what());
            info.run();
        }
    }
}
```

CryptoPP trows an exception while decrypting saying this:

**FileTransformationFilter: ciphertext length is not multiple of a block size.**

How ever it does not throw anything if decryption process is done in first function ( on_btn_encrypt() ) no file is read there, so it looks I'm having problem with reading encrypted file but have no idea how?

This is content of encrypted file:
**&`OôÍoYjÜMe×Q°Þ**

plaintext is:
**some text**

Do you see what am I missing here? thanks so much!

**EDIT:**

here are modification which solved the problem as sugested by Qmick and Artjom:

**ENCRYPTION**

```
// encrypt the file:
AES::Encryption enc(key.BytePtr(), AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption mode(enc, iv);
    
string file = m_file_name + ".aes";
FileSink* sink = new FileSink(file.c_str());
StreamTransformationFilter encryptor(mode, sink);

string plain_text = m_file_buffer->get_text();
encryptor.Put(reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(plain_text.c_str()), plain_text.length());
encryptor.MessageEnd();


// write the key:
file = m_file_name + ".key";
FileSink* out = new FileSink(file.c_str());
Base64Encoder* base64_enc = new Base64Encoder;
base64_enc->Attach(out);
base64_enc->Put(key.BytePtr(), key.size());
base64_enc->MessageEnd();



// write the iv:
file = m_file_name + ".iv";
FileSink* out2 = new FileSink(file.c_str());
Base64Encoder* base64_enc2 = new Base64Encoder;
base64_enc2->Attach(out2);
base64_enc2->Put(iv.BytePtr(), iv.size());
base64_enc2->MessageEnd();
```

**DECRYPTION:**

```
//
// read key
//
string store_key;
StringSink* string_key_in = new StringSink(store_key);
Base64Decoder* base64_key_dec = new Base64Decoder(string_key_in);

string file = "test.txt.key";
FileSource* file_key_in = new FileSource(file.c_str(), true, base64_key_dec);
    
SecByteBlock key(AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
key.Assign(reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(store_key.c_str()), store_key.size());




//
// read iv
//
string store_iv;
StringSink* string_iv_in = new StringSink(store_iv);
Base64Decoder* base64_iv_dec = new Base64Decoder(string_iv_in);

file = "test.txt.iv";
FileSource* file_iv_in = new FileSource(file.c_str(), true, base64_iv_dec);

SecByteBlock iv(AES::BLOCKSIZE);
iv.Assign(reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(store_iv.c_str()), store_iv.size());



// read ciphertext:
string store_ciphertext;
StringSink* ciphertext_in = new StringSink(store_ciphertext);

file = m_file_name;
FileSource* file_ciphertext_in = new FileSource(file.c_str(), true, ciphertext_in);

SecByteBlock cipher_text;
cipher_text.Assign(reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(store_ciphertext.c_str()), store_ciphertext.size());



//
// decrypt:
//
AES::Decryption dec(key, AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption mode(dec, iv);

file = "decrypted.txt";
FileSink* sink = new FileSink(file.c_str());
StreamTransformationFilter decryptor(mode, sink);

decryptor.Put(cipher_text.BytePtr(), cipher_text.size());
decryptor.MessageEnd();
```

Comment: The problem is `ciphertext length is not multiple of a block size.` (duh). Read about block- and padding-modes

Comment: @deviantfan, thanks, I did, and as I said in my post above there is no such problem if decryption is done without reading a file.

Comment: You have to read it in binary, because the ciphertext can contain all sorts of unprintable and whitespace characters like `\n` and `\0`.

Comment: Thanks Artjom! read/write in binary mode and also hex encoding/decoding the output solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no guarentee cipher text will not contain escape sequence like `\n`, which make `getline()` get wrong string(truncated).

So it is recommended to transform the cipher text to hex or something else to avoid escape sequence.

Comment: Thank you, hex ecnoding and also read\write in binary mode as sugested by Artjom B. solved the problem.

Comment: I edited my answer for other people in future which may encounter this kind of problem.